# Can I open some fields of gravity form inside popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have gravity form like this.

[image]

I want to open dynamic fields (after selecting dropdown) inside a popup/lightbox and want to submit the form either from popup or page.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for our plugin, [Gravity Forms Nested Forms](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/).

I typically would try and share a basic code example of how to do accomplish this without the plugin but there really is no simple solution here.